# Debian jessie screen freezes at boot

Tags: boot, debian, freeze

I recently installed debian 8 on my windows 8.1 computer. I deleted windows, installed debian with a CD, and now, I can't boot.
When I want to boot normally, I get this: (sorry for quality)

[image: result]

```
Loading, please wait...
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
/dev/sdb2: recovering journal
/dev/sdb2: clean, 152728/60497920 files, 4810330/241974272 blocks
```

just a second after, i've got screen artefacts on the last line, and a black screen with a pink thin line on the left...
I tried to boot in recovery mode, I've got a lot of things printed on the screen, and then, the same black screen.

I really don't know what to do. No error message, no clue... I'm totally lost at the moment and would be happy if you help me.
My graphic card is nvidia, i'm on a 64bits computer, and here's the output of lscpi in GRUB:

[image: result]

I also tried to reinstall, same result.

Thank you.

Comment: The `recovering journal` indicates that the system was forcefully shut down when the root file system was mounted read-write, which happens fairly late in the boot process. Here's something for you to try: on the GRUB *menu*, highlight the normal boot entry and press `e` (I think) to edit. You will get a command list. Look through it; it'll probably say `quiet` somewhere. Delete the word `quiet` and hit (again, I think) Ctrl+B to execute the command list to boot the system. That will cause the kernel to print significantly more detailed diagnostics. Show us what those say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and I get the same result as before, the black screen with the pink line... And the output goes too fast, can't take a picture, when it finishes it instantly goes in a black screen. Is there a way to freeze it ?

Comment: Okay, let's try something else. Try *replacing* `quiet` with `single`. It might not get you *exactly* the same result, and depending on what the problem is it might not even give the same result, but it should allow you to see *something*.

Comment: You can also try the default command line, without `quiet` but with `vga=0x0f00` or `vga=0x0f04`. Note that the keyboard layout used by GRUB may be different from what you are used to.